Double screen mirroring itself multiple times
I have two screens. They keep switching position (my main screen goes right although it should be left of the secondary one)
My Linux version isUbuntu 24.04.1 LTS (xubuntu is mentionned nowhere in the console when I type cat /etc/*-release which looks strange to me)
What I tried :

I went to Nvidia Settings, ajusted the position of the screens in the interface
The command xrandr --output DP-2 --left-of HDMI-0

Both methods work, but the problem reappears after a while.
